# How can I update ColumnDataSource to plot streaming line graph using periodic callback?

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I would like to make streaming line graph but I could not understand how to implement bokeh periodic callback. I checked the given examples ([1](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/spectrogram/main.py) and [2](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/ohlc/main.py)) for `ColumnDataSource` update using update function but I could not understand.

I would like to get data from database and plot (each time new data periodically). Could you please give me a very simple example?

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import time, threading
from dateutil import parser

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200)
p2 = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200)

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()

p_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
c.execute('SELECT Date_Time, Inactive_Time, signal FROM PlotData WHERE Interface=(?) AND Date_Time>(?)',('wlan0',p_time,))
data = c.fetchall()
xs = []
ys = []
zs = []
for row in data:
    xs.append(parser.parse(row[0]))
    ys.append(row[1])
    zs.append(row[2])
p.line(xs, ys, line_width=2)
p2.line(xs, zs, line_width=2)

curdoc().add_root(column(p,p2))
```

Comment: Have you tried add_periodic_callback(callback, period_milliseconds). See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38294157/2929207

Comment: yes I tried it but I couldn't make it. I also checked OHLC example for it but I couldn't understand exactly how to update ColumnDataSource. if I understand it in a simple example, I can try to implement it to my code. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/ohlc/main.py @PabloReyes

Comment: Hi Pablo, it works right now. I used ColumnDataSource as it is used in OHLC example and periodic callback but I update the data as it is given in the "sliders" example ( https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py#L66 ). It updates the all data instead of appending which is given in OHLC. I hope this helps someone else so I wanted to share. @PabloReyes